# How to read a file content at execution time? Chef reads at compile time

Tags: ruby, io, chef-infra

Because I'm running into this [MIXLIB-11](http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/MIXLIB-11) error that I've reported to Mixlib team, I need to find a walkaround, an alternative to Mixlib::Shellout.

**Briefly about the problem:**

[Here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.chef.user/1139) is a statement which says "*No surprise -- the read is happening at compile time, but the remote_file resource is actually *created* at execution time.**"

Because of this feature, `Mixlib::Shellout.new("ls", :cwd => '/opt/cubrid/share/webmanager')` raises "**No such file or directory**" error even though that directory is created at execution time by a previous recipe included in this current recipe.

**Is there a way to read a file/directory at execution time?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found an answer: wrap the code in `ruby_block`, and it will be executed at run time.

```
ruby_block "Check if CURBID Web Manager needs installation" do
  block do
    version = ""

    if File.exists?("#{CWM_HOME_DIR}/appLoader.js")
      # Read the CWM version from file.
      f = File.open("#{CWM_HOME_DIR}/appLoader.js")

      pattern = /Ext\.cwm\.prodVersion = '(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'/

      f.each {|line|
        if match = pattern.match(line)
          version = match[1]
          break
        end
      }

      f.close
    end
  end
end
```

Now the version is correctly populated from the file created in the previous recipe.

Answer (score 0):

If using custom resources, you can use the `load_current_value` method.

```
action :some_action do

  load_current_value do
    if File.exist?('/var/www/html/index.html')
      homepage IO.read('/var/www/html/index.html')
    end
    if File.exist?('/var/www/html/404.html')
      page_not_found IO.read('/var/www/html/404.html')
    end
  end

end
```

https://docs.chef.io/dsl_custom_resource.html

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to use the `type` command to read the file into a variable during execution.

To simply read the file into a variable, you can try

```
ruby_block 'Read IP file into v_ip variable' do
   block do
       if File.exists?("#{v_ip_folder}\\ip.txt")
          v_ip = %x(type "#{v_ip_folder}\\ip.txt")
          Chef::Log.info("#{v_ip}")
       end
   end
end
```

`%x(type "#{v_ip_folder}\\ip.txt")` will run the `type` command in command prompt and return the output to the `v_ip` variable specified.

Comment: The `type` command is a windows-specific command, with a completely different behavior on unix.  For that reason you should use ruby file i/o commands rather than executing system utilities.

Answer (score -4):

Consider a `remote_file`. It is executed at execution (run) time, and it can also works with local files for example:

```
remote_file "Copy file" do
  path "file:///opt/destination.txt"
  source "file:///opt/source.txt"
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode 0755
end
```

So using `remote_file` is good work around. While writing a custom code require a time and can be error prone.
See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19706896/1251549).

Comment: `remote_file` is for transferring (or copying) files, not for reading.

Comment: Your solution does not answer the question