# How to move/copy files locally with Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I haven't yet come across a Chef resource that will copy/move files locally. For example, I want to download [jetty hightide](http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-hightide-7.4.5/jetty-hightide-7.4.5.v20110725.zip) and unzip it. Once done, copy all the files into a particular folder, like this:

```
# mv /var/tmp/jetty-hightide-7.4.5.v20110725/* /opt/jetty/
```

BTW, jettyhightide when unzipped, gives you a folder and inside that folder rest of the files are located.  Hence `unzip jetty-hightide-7.4.5.v20110725.zip -d /opt/jetty/` is useless because it will create a directory `/opt/jetty/jetty-hightide-7.4.5.v20110725/*` whereas what I really want is `/opt/jetty/*`. Hence I am looking for a local copy/move resource in Chef.

Comment: can you please help me out on the below question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105976/mv-resource-in-chef/39108026#39108026

Comment: you say "copy all the files" but then you show a "mv" command, which moves *not* copies

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got it working by using `bash` resource as below:

```
bash "install_jettyhightide" do
  code <<-EOL
  unzip /var/tmp/jetty-hightide-7.4.5.v20110725.zip -d /opt/jetty/
  mv /opt/jetty/jetty-hightide-7.4.5.v20110725/* /opt/jetty/
  cp /opt/jetty/bin/jetty.sh /etc/init.d/jetty
  update-rc.d jetty defaults
  EOL
end
```

But I was really hoping for a chef way of doing it. copying/moving files locally would be the most generic task a sysadmin will need to do.

Comment: The 'chef' way of doing things would look more like the "For-each directory" example of @CAMOBAP's example -- spawn a resource for every directory and every file.  That is actually terrible for performance.  What you did is actually correct, and is the kind of use case that the bash resource is there for.  You could add a `not_if` or `creates` to check for /etc/init.d/jetty/jetty.sh being created to make it more idempotent.

Comment: NOTE: there is now the [archive_file](https://docs.chef.io/resources/archive_file/) resource in chef-client which is better than most of these roll-your-own-execute-resource approaches

Answer (score 112):

## How to copy single file

### First way

I use `file` statement to copy file (compile-time check)

```
file "/etc/init.d/someService" do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode 0755
  content ::File.open("/home/someService").read
  action :create
end
```

here :

- `"/etc/init.d/someService"` - target file,
- `"/home/someService"` - source file

Also you can wrap `::File.open("/home/someService").read` in `lazy` block

```
...
lazy { ::File.open("/home/someService").read }
...
```

### Second way

User `remote_file` statement (run-time check)

```
remote_file "Copy service file" do 
  path "/etc/init.d/someService" 
  source "file:///home/someService"
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode 0755
end
```

### Third way

Also you can use shell/batch

## For-each directory

```
Dir[ "/some/directory/resources/**/*" ].each do |curr_path|
  file "/some/target/dir/#{Pathname.new(curr_path).basename}" do
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode 0755
    content lazy { IO.read(curr_path, mode: 'rb').read }
    action :create
  end if File.file?(curr_path)
  directory "/some/target/dir/#{File.dirname(curr_path)}" do
    path curr_path
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode 0755
    action :create
  end if File.directory?(curr_path)
end
```

This is just idea, because sub-paths in this example is not handled correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I wish the `file` resource had a `content_file` attribute or something. This seems like a fairly common thing to do.

Comment: Great answer! I especially like the 'First way' above, since if the file contents aren't changed it will not update the file. It's worth mentioning that if the source file is managed by Chef, then the ::File.open *must* be wrapped in a lazy block, otherwise Chef will fail to find the file at compile time. The lazy attribute is only available in Chef >= 11.6, >= 10.28 (I believe).

Comment: It's good to point out that using a remote file will get around Chef requiring the file to exist at compile time.

Comment: Please add a remark that diference between `remote_file` and `file` is also that `file` is executed at **compile** time, while `remote_file` is executed at **run** time. So when you need to work with files at run time - `remote_file`is a good work around.

Comment: Definitely note that for binary files you'll need to change it to `IO.read(curr_path, mode: 'rb')` or risk corrupting the destination file.

Comment: **remote_file** did the trick for me as it allowed me to keep track of file deltas automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I know this question have already been answered, and discussed, but here is the method I use when creating files.

1. First include the file under the cookbook's files/default folder
2. Then on your recipe use the `cookbook_file` resource

e.g:

```
cookbook_file "/server/path/to/file.ext" do
  source "filename.ext"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 00600
  action :create_if_missing
end
```

From chef documentation: https://docs.chef.io/resources/cookbook_file/

> The cookbook_file resource is used to transfer files from a
> sub-directory of the *files/* directory in a cookbook to a specified
> path that is located on the host running the chef-client or chef-solo.

Comment: This post is about moving files already on the target machine to another location on the target machine. cookbook_file cannot do that. cookbook_file is used to copy files from the cookbook to the target machine, not locally around the target machine.

Comment: I do some action with use `copy` module on **Ansible**, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You could give the [ark](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/ark) cookbook a try. This extracts the file for you and you afterwards notice an `execute` resource.

Comment: +1 I can highly recommend this cookbook. Simplifies he handling of archive files. Also supports source installs.

Comment: Yes, I knew about ark. but that would be an overkill to use it just for copy/move. My main intention is to copy/move files and not installing them vi .tar/.zip archive. I really wonder why opscode did not consider creating a chef-way of copy/move files.

Comment: Yes, I somehow agree. But they can't start a product with support for everyting. Ark is also fine for simple unpackaging, even with out the ./configure && make && make install dance.

Comment: There is now an [archive_file](https://docs.chef.io/resources/archive_file/) resource built into chef-client.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the way you've done it and accepted it, if you only wanted to run one command like you initially asked (copy or move), and not run a block of commands, then you could do it with the [execute](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html) resource:

```
execute "copy_core" do
    command "mv /var/tmp/jetty-hightide-7.4.5.v20110725 /opt/jetty"
    user "root"
end
```

Maybe this will help someone else looking at this in the future.

Comment: Warning here: this will run the mv again and again at each chef run if no guard is added, if a file in target has been modified, any change will be lost.

Comment: @Tensibai, he just asked how to perform the 'mv' command in Chef. It all depends on where you put this block. You can always add `not_if { File.exist?("/opt/jetty") }` in the block so it doesn't redo it if it's already been copied.

Comment: The warning is for future readers of this question/answers. (And solving a XY problem is not always the best thing to do)

Answer (score 2):

I would actually use something like the following (notice "binread") as this would work for text files and binary files. using "read" would yield surprising results with binary files particularly if you use both unix and windows systems.

```
file destination do
  content IO.binread(source)
  action  :create
end
```

Comment: This is actually quite important, working with stuff like Java Keystore files will break if you use the default read method.

Answer (score 0):

If your recipe is already tied to Windows, you can use embedded PowerShell scripts, like this:

```
# Copy files from "C:/foo/lib" to "C:/foo"
powershell_script "copy_lib" do
  code <<-EOH
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
      Get-ChildItem -Path "C:/foo/lib" -File | Foreach-Object {
        Copy-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Destination "C:/foo" -Force
      }
  EOH
end

# Delete "C:/foo/lib" folder
powershell_script "delete_lib" do
  code <<-EOH
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    Remove-Item -Path "C:/foo/lib" -Recurse
  EOH
end
```

Answer (score -1):

**To Copy files locally in CHEF**

```
file "C:/Users/Administrator/chef/1.xml" 

do         --->       tar content lazy 

{

IO.read("C:/Users/Administrator/chef-repo/cookbooks/2.xml")

} -->src

action :create

end
```

Comment: Non working code, and the idea is already in a previous answer above)