# chef copying a directory

Tags: directory, copy, chef-infra

I'm trying to copy a directory from one folder to another folder like so:

```
directory "C:\\test\\go" do
  recursive true
  action :create
end

cookbook_file "C:\\Automation" do
  source "C:\\Automation"
  path "C:\\test\\go"
  action :create_if_missing
end
```

It creates the target folder C:\test\go but does not copy anything.
The documentation says that it should also handle directories so any ideas why it does not?
I've also tried a wildcard source "C:\Automation\*" and also tried forward slashed...

Comment: This is not what a "cookbook_file" resource is used for. See: http://docs.opscode.com/resource_cookbook_file.html Use a ruby block or just call the OS specific copy command.

Comment: Thanks. Funny that I've been using pure ruby cp_r and someone who is experienced in chef told me to use cookbook_file instead.

Comment: You'll likely want to use rsync or just mount the remote folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221252/how-to-move-copy-files-locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
ruby_block "get the windows resources" do
  block do
    FileUtils.mkdir_p mod_path
    FileUtils.cp_r(Dir["#{RESOURCE_DIR}/*.exe"], Chef::Config[:file_cache_path])
  end
end
```