# backup a directory with a chef resource?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm wondering if there's a resource out there to make a copy of a whole directory. I know I could always use a bash resource and just do a 'cp', but I was wondering if there's an analog to the 'file' resource for directories.

bash resource solution

```
bash "backup org folder" do
  code <<-EOL
  mkdir /opt/tmp/copy
  mv /opt/tmp/org/* /opt/tmp/copy

  EOL
end
```

I found this: [How to move/copy files locally with Chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221252/how-to-move-copy-files-locally-with-chef)
But is 2 years old so I'm wondering if there's any new resource for this case.

Thanks.

Comment: please check this http://serverfault.com/questions/428970/copy-a-whole-directory-structure-in-chef handling recursive copying of directory structure with chef

Comment: sorry maybe I wasn't clear.  I would like to copy a local directory and all it's contents to a different location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to do this is using the bash resource but there are a few things you need to be careful with.

```
 bash "backup testDir directory" do
  user "jhon"
  cwd "/opt/lnp"
  environment ({'HOME' => '/home/jhon', 'USER' => 'jhon'})
  code <<-EOL
  {
    mv /opt/lnp/testDir/* /opt/lnp/testDir.#{TODAY}
  }
  EOL
  not_if { Dir['/opt/lnp/testDir/*'].empty? }
end
```

1. If you need to do the copy as a specific user you need to initialize the environment
2. in order to avoid an error if the folder is empty you should check if the directory is empty via a not_if block

Answer (score 1):

No other way as per my knowledge. Either you have to use a bash resource as you have done or through a Ruby block